# MacOS loses contact with “Internet”

Tags: network

I am having a surreal problem that started after an accident damaged the screen and it was replaced, Apple’s techs also wiping the hard-drive just for good measure.

My MacBook Pro running Sonoma occasionally loses contact with the Internet. `ping 8.8.8.8`, the lowest level operation I can think of, just times out.

It has both WiFi, which still claims to be working, and an Ethernet connection.  Disconnecting either has no visible effect.  The only way I have found to address the problem is to reboot, which dispels the problem for a period that varies from 20 seconds to two weeks.

It must, I think, be an OS problem, since

- it affects two nearly unrelated systems, Ethernet and WiFi, so it cannot be a hardware problem
- it doesn’t affect any of the dozens of other people using the same WiFi and the same Ethernet, so it isn’t a systemic problem.

I thought it had something to do with Slack, since the application would always be frozen when I had that problem, but not turning on Slack at all does not solve the problem, so I think I was reversing cause and effect.

All the online sources I can find give useless generic advice like “check your cables!” (on my WiFi?)

I haven’t found anything specific that seems to trigger it.  It *seems* a little more common in the first minute or two after wake-up, but maybe not.

Any suggestions?  Even some diagnostics would help.

Comment: do you have the controll of the router to reset it

Comment: @Ruskes — not really, and there are 40 other people using the same router, so I don’t think it is malfunctioning.  If it were, why would rebooting _my_ machine fix the problem?

Comment: Go to WiFi and Delete that profile and start over, you might need the password

Comment: You said Google's techs wiped the hard drive; was the device sent in to Google for repair...? Did you subsequently reinstall the OS? Did you restore from a backup, or set it up as a fresh installation? Can you ping devices on your local network successfully?

Comment: @JMY1000 — sorry, the repairs were done by _Apple_, of course.  They reinstalled the OS and I set it up as a fresh installation.  I don’t know if there is a local device that I can ping; I will try while it is working.

Comment: @Ruskes — the profile for the network?  There are several networks available and none of them work.  Deleting and recreating one has not helped.

Comment: Theory... during the screen replacement the antenna/cable on the airport chip was damaged

Comment: Which model MacBook?  Is the Ethernet built in or are you using a USB Ethernet adapter?  Are they both active/connected at the same time?  Do you lose connection with your LAN as well?  Try pinging your router to see if it responds.

Comment: I'd capture the output from ifconfig before and during the issue and see if anything significant has changed. Might be something low level on the interfaces. Then check the routing rules too, and capture working and broken: route -v get slack.com I'm also curious the order of the network devices, as if the first one gets hung it might not try the second and appear as if it's broken.

Comment: @MichaelLorton If you go to Settings -> Wi-Fi Details -> TCP/IP, it should show you your router; try pinging that.